# Vue data table expandable row issue

Tags: vue.js, datatable, row, expandable, vuestic

**Problem:** I cannot add an expandable row in my data table. It is not showing.

**Goal:** I need to populate some data in my data table with an expandable row.

**What I have tried:** I have followed the documentation, [here is the reproducible code that you can access on codepen](https://codepen.io/qureshiharis/pen/JjNQVQJ). You can see after uncommenting the code which populates my Data table, the expandable row isn't visible anymore.

**Code used to add expandable row:**

```
     <template v-slot:top>
    <v-toolbar flat>
      <v-toolbar-title>Data</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-switch v-model="singleExpand" label="Single expand" class="mt-2"></v-switch>
    </v-toolbar>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">More info about {{ item.name }}</td>
  </template>
```

**Code used to add data in Data table:**

```
<!--       <template  v-slot:body="props">
    <tr v-for="index in props.items" :key="index.Info">
      <td id="table-data" v-for="header in headers" :key="header.Info" class="text-left">
        {{ index.packetParsed[header.value] }}
      </td> 
    </tr>      
  </template> -->
```

**Note:** Please note that I cannot change the structure of data as it is retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have mentioned that the structure of data can't be changed

in the codepen which you have provided, there I saw data as

`dataFromDatabase: [ { packetParsed: { Name: "Bill", Address: "NY", Contact: "1234", Info: "Mgr", }, packetParsed: { Name: "Tom", Address: "CA", Contact: "9876", Info: "Sr Mgr", }, }, ],`

can you please explain why the data has an object which contains objects with the same key (Note: we can read only the last object if all the keys are same when you read )

as per the documentation of vuetify expandable table, items prop should be an array with unique item objects .

but you have provided an array with a single object( which has multiple objects with same key )

Comment: You are right, I was able to fix it by getting data from the database and then parsing it in the correct format as required by the Data table! Thank you so much!